# What is wrong with these evergreen trees?

Tags: flowers

Can anyone identify what kind of evergreen trees are these and what is wrong with them
[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like blue spruce, Picea pungens 'Koster', also known as Colorado spruce. These are fairly tolerant of various conditions, including some drought, once they are mature, but yours may have suffered some drought when they were smaller, which would explain the loss of some of the lower branches/foliage. The growth higher up looks healthy, although aesthetically, the overall shape isn't fantastic; this may or may not improve as the trees age.

Unfortunately, once needles have died and fallen from a branch, growth will only continue from the tips of the branch and will not regrow in the bare areas. Which is likely why the other tree has had its lower branches removed, because they died back. Further info https://www.gardenia.net/plant/Picea-pungens-Koster

Comment: Spider mites can be a problem for blue spruce. They attack lower branches near the trunk. It is possible that these trees were pruned to remove  damaged lower branches.

Comment: Needle cast fungus can also be an issue, primarily in more humid environments (I live in SW Michigan). You'll tend to notice more damage on the northern sides of trees which don't get as much direct sunlight.

Comment: @blacksmith37: The other day, I was working in the garden, and sought some relief in the shade of a tree that overhangs the corner of the garden. I remember remarking that there were spider mites crawling everywhere on the papers I was diagraming stuff on. I was thinking, why are there so many here, as it was just a pile of wood chips. Now it makes sense: the tree I was under was exactly that: a blue spruce.